# Effective way to fetch 'n' number of radio options from HTML form using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am currently working on a quiz program, where the form has about 20 questions.
Using PHP I know how to fetch the results in the action page.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action = "result.php">
Question 1:
<input type='radio' name='Q1' value='Op1' /> Op1
<input type='radio' name='Q1' value='Op2' /> Op2
<input type='radio' name='Q1' value='Op3' /> Op3
<input type='radio' name='Q1' value='Op4' /> Op4

Question 2:
<input type='radio' name='Q2' value='Op1' /> Op1
<input type='radio' name='Q2' value='Op2' /> Op2
<input type='radio' name='Q2' value='Op3' /> Op3
<input type='radio' name='Q2' value='Op4' /> Op4
.
.
.
.
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.php**

```
<?PHP
$answer1 = $_POST['Q1'];
$answer2 = $_POST['Q2'];
.
.
?>
```

This doesn't seem neat at all, is there any effective way to fetch the option selected in the front-end for all those questions, rather than writing 20 statements.

TIA

Comment: If they are individual form questions, then it makes perfect sense to do it the way you have

Comment: I'm still learning php, so I would to this:

`for($i = 0 ; $i < 20 ; $i++) {
  $postarray = 'q' . ($i + 1);
  $answer[$i] = $_POST[$postarray];
 }`

Comment: First off, it'd be `$_POST['Q1']` and `$_POST['Q2']`. Then, if these are individual questions, what's the problem about bringing or referring the result as `$_POST''Qx']` if it's just where the info about the answer is referenced. It depends on how you are going to use those results.

Comment: @Derek, the twenty questions come from a single form

Comment: you'll need to show the origin of the data first (meaning the submitted form), everything will depend on it, we can suggest anything from for loops, foreach loops, arrays and everything but we can only guess on our end on how our suggestions will fit on that data that you have

Comment: @CésarEscudero, that's one way to do it. Yes, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that allows you to iterate the specific radio button answers is to store them in their own array.

For example

```
<input type="radio" name="radio[Q1]" value="Op1">
<input type="radio" name="radio[Q1]" value="Op2">

<input type="radio" name="radio[Q2]" value="Op1">
<input type="radio" name="radio[Q2]" value="Op2">
```

Then you can iterate the values with a `foreach` loop

```
foreach($_POST['radio'] as $question => $answer) {
    // $question will be "Q1", "Q2", etc
    // $answer will be the chosen radio button value
}
```

Having all the radio buttons under one *name* (ie `"radio"`) allows you to distinguish these keys and values from other form fields you might want to include.

---

Also, your `<form>` should have `method="post"` but I figured you probably already have that.